# C++11 constexpr compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

I am trying to declare a `constexpr` and it throws compilation errors.

```
static constexpr float goBaseMovementSpeed = (1.135f / 440.f);
```

Why is this line not working?

> error C2144: syntax error : 'float' should be preceded by ';'
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

`goBaseMovementSpeed` is a member of a class.

Compiler: Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2015, i can't get it working on g++11 either

Comment: Post a minimal example that reproduces the error then. It works fine for me too: http://ideone.com/jYWmgS

Comment: It compiles fine on MSVS 2015

Comment: Probably you have missed some semi-colon before the line of constexpr

Comment: it's because I was compiling with Visual Studio 2013, I thought it had c++11 installed? Some of the C++11 classes such as std::chrono work. What should the problem be?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, Kerrek SB, runDOSrun, Code Different, Tushar - Please forgive my ignorance... Why was the question closed with reason *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")"* The original question had the line being compiled and the compiler error produced by the line. He does not seem to be seeking debugging help; rather, he's trying to understand the compile error for that particular line.

Comment: Hi @jww, I don't know why I got so many down votes, I guess my question was not very productive for everyone's interest, and maybe I shouldn't have been so sure of myself when I said I was using VS 2015. Personally, I think in the end it doesn't even matter and I hope other users can stumble upon this question more easily now through Google, this way making the community better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 does not support all the C++11 features. In the same time it supports tiny part of C++14 features like `std::make_unique` for example.

`constexpr` is not supported on Visual Studio 2013.

For the full list:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx